# Why is android not recognizing the loadurl method?

Tags: java, android

```
if (mItem != null) {
    (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.apple).loadUrl(mItem.urls);
}

return rootView;
```

I don't know why android is not recognizing this method and counting it as an error. (the loadurl method with the arrow underneath) I am trying to load the webpage from the m items into the webview.

Comment: `((WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.apple)).loadUrl(mItem.urls);`?

Answer (score 3):

The cast is incomplete/misplaced. This is probably what you meant:

```
((WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.apple)).loadUrl(mItem.urls);
```

The cast, as you placed it, casts the expression `rootView.findViewById(R.id.apple).loadUrl(mItem.urls)` to a `WebView`, which doesn't make sense. You want to carry specifically `rootView.findViewById(R.id.apple)`.

The type of the value returned by `findView` is `View`, not a `WebView`, hence the compiler error you got.